# Chart.js Line chart Option does not disable gridlines

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm new with chart.js and have tried to manage "option: in the javascript, but is seems that xAxes: option is totally neglected.

I have also tried other examples like grid colors etc, but the "options:" still does not work.
Could you please have a check on this simple code what goes wrong? I use Edge.

Best regards,

Cornelis

See here the code:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
    labels: [1500,1600,1700,1750,1800,1850,1900,1950,1999,2050],
    datasets: [{
      data: [86,114,106,106,107,111,133,221,783,2478],
       borderColor: "#3e95cd",
       fill: false,
       tension: 0.1,
       label: 'Name of label'}
       ] 
    },
   
    options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display:false
            }   
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display:false
            }   
        }]
     }//Scales  
    }//Option
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:30vh; width:50vw">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.min.js"></script>    
<canvas id="myChart" width="70" height="20"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no `gridLines` option in chart.js 3.5.0 https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/

Answer (score 1):

You are using v3 of the lib while your options object syntax is in v2, please read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.0/getting-started/v3-migration.html) to check if you need to change anything else, for this issue all the scales are now a seperate object instead as listed as x and y axes in an array, also the prop name has changed.

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are completely right, I used the outdated version of chart.sj. In addition, 'Options' and 'options' will also make the difference.